# How to run a python app repeatedly using Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

The Bluemix python build pack works just fine - very easy to `cf push myapp --no-route`. So far, so good.

#### A question, though:

I want to run it periodically on Bluemix as I would using `cron` on my local system.

#### Background

The app is not written as a long-running task. I just run it periodically to collect data from several websites that I have written for my clients and to email me results when appropriate.

When I run it on IBM Bluemix though, the Bluemix runtime currently thinks the app is failing when it exits and needs to be restarted immediately. This is not what I want, of course.

Comment: Have you considered trying something like https://github.com/18F/cg-cron, or https://github.com/dbader/schedule, or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be incredibly easy after having got my head around *Openwhisk*'s simple **trigger**; **action**; **rule** model.

So I migrated my Python app to  *Openwhisk* entirely rather than use the Bluemix Python buildpack or Bluemix Docker containers neither of which were appropriate to this task's simple needs.

I include a summary below. I wrote a  more verbose version [here](https://iainhouston.com/blog/openwhisk-workflow.html).

As an added bonus I was able to remove a good deal of my own code and instead use [Slack](https://slack.com) for notifications. As it was so simple to do, I include it in this answer.

### The program

Openwhisk Python actions are python 2.7.
File `sitemonitor.py`:

```
def main(inDict):
  inTimeout = inDict.get('timeout', '4')
  // A few function calls omitted for brevity
  if state.errorCount == 0:
    return {'text': "All sites OK"}
  else:
    return { 'text' : state.slackMessage }
```

`main` takes a dictionary and returns a dictionary

### Setting up the job

#### Create the `sitemonitor` action

`timeout` is a parameter specific to my app only.

```
$ wsk action create sitemonitor sitemonitor.py # default timeout of 4 seconds
```

or give the action a different timeout in a default parameter

```
$ wsk action update sitemonitor sitemonitor.py --param timeout 2 # seconds
```

#### Create the Slack package action `monitorSlack`

```
wsk package bind  /whisk.system/slack monitorSlack \
  --param url 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...' \
  --param username 'monitor-bot' \
  --param channel '#general'
```

Find the [Incoming Webhook URL from your Slack Team account](https://slack.com)

#### Create the composed `monitor2slack` action

```
$ wsk action create monitor2slack --sequence sitemonitor,monitorSlack/post
```

#### Create the trigger

It will fire automatically every other hour

```
$ wsk trigger create monitor2hrs \
    --feed /whisk.system/alarms/alarm \
    --param cron '0 0 */2 * * *' 

$ wsk trigger fire monitor2hrs # fire manually to test
```

#### Create the rule

```
$ wsk rule create monitorsites monitor2hrs monitor2slack
```

... and *Openwhisk* will do the rest.

### References

[Openwhisk documentation](https://new-console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/) : very good

People at the `#openwhisk` channel in the the Slack [`dW Open`Team](https://slack.com) were very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple options:

1) If you want to do it completely in Python, you could try something like I did in [this example](http://blog.4loeser.net/2015/07/bluemix-simple-cron-like-service-for-my.html). The basic structure is like this:

```
import schedule  
 import time 

 def job():  
 #put the task to execute here  

 def anotherJob():  
 #another task can be defined here  

 schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)  
 schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(anotherJob)  

while True:  
   schedule.run_pending()  
   time.sleep(1)
```

2) Bluemix has changed and today a better approach would be to use [OpenWhisk](https://developer.ibm.com/openwhisk/). It is IBM's version of "serverless" computing and it allows to schedule execution of tasks or do it event-driven. You could move your app into a Docker container and invoke it based on a schedule or driven by external events.

Comment: Useful suggestions, thanks @data_henrik. I favour the OpenWhisk approach going forward. I'm exploring this right now and hope to provide a detailed answer when I've succeeded. I've run my python app containerised in Bluemix; I've configured a skeleton Openwhisk  trigger; action; and rule but it seems OpenWhisk only deals with Docker Hub containers and not  Bliuemix containers ... but that's another question which I need to answer elsewhere.

Comment: I have answered the part of the question about how to adapt my existing Python as an OpenWhisk Docker action [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154762/how-do-i-make-a-python-docker-image-an-openwhisk-action/39154763#39154763) with detailed commands, narrative and program [here on GitHub](https://github.com/iainhouston/dockerPython). I will next provide an answer on this page to my question detailing the OpenWhisk triggers and rules part of the answer.