# How do I make a Python Docker image an OpenWhisk action?

Tags: python, docker, openwhisk

I have a Docker image  which runs a Python program. I want now to run this container as an OpenWhisk action. How do I do this?

I have seen several examples in other programming languages, and an excellent [black box](http://blog.altoros.com/how-to-use-openwhisk-docker-actions-in-ibm-bluemix.html) skeleton approach in C and Node.js. but I want to understand more about how OpenWhisk interacts with the container and, if possible, employ just Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a lot simpler now (Sept 2016) than in my previous answer.

After having  created the `dockerSkeleton` directory with the command `$ wsk sdk install docker` all you have to do is to edit the `Dockerfile` and make sure your Python (2.7 right now)  is accepting parameters and supplying outputs in the appropriate format.

Here's a summary. I've written it up in greater detail [here on GitHub](https://github.com/iainhouston/dockerPython)

#### The program

File `test.py` (or `whatever_name.py` you will use in your edited `Dockerfile` below.)

- Make sure it's executable (`chmod a+x test.py`).
- Make sure it's got the  shebang on line one.
- Make sure it runs locally.

  - e.g. `./test.py '{"tart":"tarty"}'`
    produces the JSON dictionary:
    `{"allparams": {"tart": "tarty", "myparam": "myparam default"}}`

```
 
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import sys
    import json

    def main():
      # accept multiple '--param's
      params = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
      # find 'myparam' if supplied on invocation
      myparam = params.get('myparam', 'myparam default')

      # add or update 'myparam' with default or 
      # what we were invoked with as a quoted string
      params['myparam'] = '{}'.format(myparam)

      # output result of this action
      print(json.dumps({ 'allparams' : params}))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

#### The Dockerfile

Compare the following with the supplied `Dockerfile` to take the Python script `test.py` and ready it to build the docker image.

Hopefully the comments explain the differences. Any assets (data files or modules) in the current directory will become part of the image as will any Python dependencies listed in `requirements.txt`

```
# Dockerfile for Python whisk docker action
FROM openwhisk/dockerskeleton

ENV FLASK_PROXY_PORT 8080

# Install our action's Python dependencies
ADD requirements.txt /action/requirements.txt
RUN cd /action; pip install -r requirements.txt

# Ensure source assets are not drawn from the cache 
# after this date
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2016-09-05T13:59:39Z
# Add all source assets
ADD . /action
# Rename our executable Python action
ADD test.py /action/exec

# Leave CMD as is for Openwhisk
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd actionProxy && python -u actionproxy.py"]
```

Note the `ENV REFRESHED_AT ...` which I used to make sure that an updated `test.py` layer is picked up afresh rather than being drawn from the cache when the image is built.

Comment: What comes down to is that the container needs to provide a REST API on port 8080 with two endpoints `/init` and `/run` init will run once this your opportunity to setup your function anything you need to download, or anything global state you want to setup, then `/run` will get run many times without running `/init' this is what we call warm seed it container Here is another example https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/tree/master/core/pythonAction

Comment: @csantanapr I updated the bit about `/init` in the light of your input. Many thanks.

Comment: Our comments above relate to the original answer which has since been invalidated by the simpler Sept 2016 Openwhisk.